# storing the results of a loop quickly Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, pandas

I have a function that I call on every row of a pandas DataFrame and I would like to store the result of each function call (each iteration). Below is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
data =[{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}, {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}]
InputData = pd.DataFrame(data)

ResultData = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])

def SomeFunction(row):
    #Function code goes here (not important to this question)#
    ##########################################################
    ##########################################################
    return Temp 


for index, row in InputData.iterrows():
    # Temp will equal the result of the function (a DataFrame with 3 columns and 1 Row)
    Temp = Somefunction(row)

    # If ResultData is not empty append Temp to ResultData
    if len(ResultData) != 0:
        ResultData = ResultData.append(Temp, ignore_index = True)
    # If ResultData is empty Result data = Temp
    else:
        ResultData = Temp
```

I hope my example is easy to follow.

In my real example I have about a million rows in the Input Data and this process is very slow and I think it is the appending of the DataFrame which is making it so slow. Is there maybe a different data structure I could use which could store the three values of the "Temp" DataFrame which could be appended at the end to form the "ResultData" DataFrame?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What your function does is very important to this question. It's practically the only thing that matters.

Comment: `df.iterrows()` return a series which is kind of slow, do you really need a series in `SomeFunction`?

Comment: @StevenG - What i need is every value of each row. i.e in this example i need 1,2,3. I guess it doesnt need to be a series, it could be a list or some other data structure.

Comment: then use `df.itertuples()` and change your `SomeFunction`.  use a list to store your result as anonymous said below

Comment: You can efficiently apply a function to a dataframe or dataframe slice and get a new dataframe as result, unfortunately I lack time to post a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

Best to avoid any explicit loops in pandas. Using apply is still a little slow but probably faster than a loop.

```
df["newcol"] = df.apply(function, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a list of lists will solve your problem:

```
Result_list = []

for ... :
  ...
  Result_list.append([data1, data2, data3]);
```

To review the data:

```
for Current_data in Result_list:
   data1 = Current_data[0]
   data2 = Current_data[1]
   data3 = Current_data[2]
```

Hope it helps!